# Flutter - Exclude specific linter rule in analysis_options.yaml for a folder

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, lint, dart-analyzer

I have a bigger project with different rules for the linter written down in the analysis_options yaml file. I want to exclude a subset of rules for certain folders.

Example: I want to exclude the hole "lib/application" folder for the rule "prefer_relative_imports"

```
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - lib/injection.dart

linter:
  rules:
    - discarded_futures
    - prefer_relative_imports
```

How can i explain a folder location to ignore a subset of rules?
Excluding them in each file individually is not practical when there are a large number of files in said folder.

I tried to have multiple analysis_options.yaml files in the corresponding exluding folders to declare rules which needs to be excluded. This has no effect to the linter cause only the file in root directory seems to be noted.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new `analysis_options.yaml` file in that directory and customize its analyzer, linter... as you want.

Comment: As written I tried exactly this, but no file changed the result. It seems like no other analysis_options file is regarded.